# Javascript object literal, how to solve context?

Tags: javascript, closures, this

I would like to start organizing my code properly, so I want to use object literals. In the following case, I'm doing a pseudo class. I would like that `init()` could work as a constructor, but unfortunately, I'm not seeing how to set attributes based on object context.

```
    var car = {
    context : this,
    wheels : 0,
    color : '',
    speed : 0,
    init : (function(x){
        console.log(x);
        x.wheels = 4;
        x.color = 'red';
        x.speed = 120;
    })(context)
};

console.log(car.color);
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve?
And how is it different from say: `var car = new Car();`

Comment: An Object object doesn't have a `this` property, only Function objects do. And in a function, `this` is a keyword that belongs to the activation object (effectively a variable), it is not a public property. Finally, a function's `this` is set by the call, you can't set it statically (though you can sort of using ES5 and *bind*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't immediately run a function like that whilst declaring an object literal. What you can do:

```
var car = {
init : function(wheels,color,speed){
    this.wheels = wheels || 0;
    this.color = color || '';
    this.speed = speed || 0;
    return this;
  }
}.init(4,'red',120);

alert(car.speed); //=>120
```

Which removes the need for:

```
context : this,
wheels : 0,
color : '',
speed : 0,
```

<strike>...and offers the possibility for:</strike>

```
var car = {
    init : function(wheels,color,speed){
      this.wheels = wheels || 0;
      this.color = color || '';
      this.speed = speed || 0;
      return this;
     }
    },
    redAndFast = car.init(4,'red',230),
    threeWheeler = car.init(3,'yellowstriped',110);
```

[**edit**] What *was* I thinking? If you want more instances of Car, you'll have to use a real `constructor` function instead of an object literal:

```
var Car = function(){
  return {
    init : function(wheels,color,speed){
            this.wheels = wheels || 0;
            this.color = color || '';
            this.speed = speed || 0;
            return this;
  }
 }
},
redAndFast = new Car().init(4,'red',230),
threeWheeler = new Car().init(3,'yellowstriped',110);
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
var Car = function(wheels,color,speed){
            this.wheels = wheels || 0;
            this.color = color || '';
            this.speed = speed || 0;
    },
    redAndFast = new Car(4,'red',230),
    threeWheeler = new Car(3,'yellowstriped',110);
```

Or if you wanted to cling on to some `init` like function:

```
var Car = (function(){
    function car(wheels,color,speed){
            this.wheels = wheels || 0;
            this.color = color || '';
            this.speed = speed || 0;
    }
    return {
        init: function(w,c,s){
            return new car(w,c,s);
        }
    };
 })(),
 redAndFast   = Car.init(4,'red',230),
 threeWheeler = Car.init(3,'yellowstriped',110);
```

But hey, what happened to my `context`? you may ask. Well, it turns out you didn't need it after all. Isn't javascript a beautiful and flexible language?

Comment: Could someone explain, what the outer brackets in var Car = (function...)() are doing? I guess they execute that function at parse time, but why is this required? (and yes, it seems to be required, otherwise 'has no method init' is thrown when trying to execute init) Do we always need to execute functions at parse time when exposing inner functions?

Answer (score 4):

```
var Car = function() {
    this.wheels = 4;
    this.color = 'red';
    this.speed = 120;
}

var car = new Car();
```

It's best to use normal constructors for these kind of tasks.

Comment: +1 from me, I like plain, simple constructors. Having a constructor return some other object than `this` is just a waste of an object and creates needless complexity. The constructor **is** the `init` function. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Object literals work for singletons. If you want an instantiable object, you'll need to learn how js oop works and just use function objects.